# Update empty column to be same value of other colum

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that haves 2 columns called "name" and "city_name",
In case "city_name" is empty update/set to same value of "name". In mysql can i create some kind of if statements and update the way i want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  You need to demonstrate your efforts...

Comment: Yes, you use `WHERE` to achieve what you want. `UPDATE ... SET city_name=name WHERE city_name='';`

Comment: @Qirel Kind of. If OP's column has NULL values, then `''` isn't considered as being empty if there are NULL values in there.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `CASE` statement here like

```
update table1
set city_name = case when city_name is null then name else city_name end;
```

(OR) just using a `WHERE` clause

```
update table1
set city_name = name
where city_name is null;
```

Comment: I think you're missing a where clause. `In case "city_name" is empty update/set to same value of "name"`  could save some IO by only doing it when city_name is empty.

Comment: that would depend on what Pedro means by empty.  If '' then no if null then yes. or handle both cases in your where clause like `Where coalesce(city_name,'')=''`